# Can't login after installing AMD driver in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I can't login to my ubuntu dekstop after install amd driver in my ubuntu 14.04 , i use lenovo ideapad 110 with amd r5 grafik,  how can i fix it ? Help me please...

Comment: Are you saying your password changed?

Comment: No, i can't login after install amd driver.. When i enter the pasword, just back to login..

Answer (score 0):

**Change your drivers from the ones that are not working via the Commandline.**

Log into the console, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Use this command to list the available drivers.

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Then pick one of the alternate drivers from the list and install it with.  Picking the one referred as recommended may be a failsafe.  Some manual proprietary drivers might not show up on the list.  You may have to reinstall a proprietary drives using the supplied install method to switch to that one.

```
$ sudo apt install [driver]
```

You may or may not have to remove or rename your current `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.  Some propriety driver installs may reconfigure it.  I would test first without touching it.  If you need to you can rm move it with.

```
$ rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Now reboot.  Now that you have a failsafe way to get back to the GUI, you can test other drivers to optimize your performance.

**Note:**

You can check your current driver that is in use with:

```
$ sudo lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3
```